# How to add a hyperlink in a text translation in prestashop?

Tags: hyperlink, prestashop

When I try to choose a product, when it is out of stock, it shows me the following mesage "There are not enough products in stock". So I want to make the "products" hyperlink.

I tried to edit the products with `<a>` tags. So I wrote it like this:

```
There are not enough <a href="www.example">products</a> in stock
```

, but unfortunately it didn't work and it shows me the `<a>` tags as a text.

How can I make the word products a hyperlink?

The Prestashop version is 1.7.5.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I tried to edit the products with <a> tags. So i wrote it like this There are not enough <a href="www.example">products</a> in stock, but unfortunately it didn't work and it shows me the <a> tags as a text.

Comment: Where did you do those changes?

Comment: The path was Translations -> choose theme translation (theme and language) -> Shop -> Notifications -> Error and i edited the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the theme folder and find 
`theme_name/templates/catalog/_partials/product-add-to-cart.tpl`
 in there find 
`{$product.availability_message}`
 and modify it like this 
`{$product.availability_message nofilter}`. 
It should help
P.S. Do not forgot to clear cache and recompile

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I made the hyperlink, but show me the word that i made hyperlink, too far from the other sentence, i mean it has a long distance from the previous word.

Comment: Do you know how can i fix it? But anyway, thanks a lot for the previous answer!

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem you say. So, check out if you don't have any css styles which can cause the issue